# Why is Ether value 0, but the contract specifies over 500 ether were transferred? How does this work?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, etherscan, smart-contract-wallets

I am interested in this tx hash:

0x526b21b2bb3556a199a5794b053a8be229ddae99aa222bc300b0efaba1f1fc01

As you can tell from Etherscan, the Ether value is 0. However, the contract it was sent to (0x94b18793b93b524b110fead408b955422b982fa4) says there is a transfer worth 585 Ether. My question is why does the value appear as 0?

I understand the value being 0 when no Ether is transferred, but rather a different token. However, I cannot understand why the value, in this case, is 0 when the transaction has been handled in Eth.

Can someone please help me understand? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

[The transaction you ask about](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x526b21b2bb3556a199a5794b053a8be229ddae99aa222bc300b0efaba1f1fc01) is a smart contract call with no `msg.value` set. The "Value" field on etherscan is set only if there is some ETH sent with the smart contract call, it does not take any ETH sending / receiving done by the contract into account.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your answer. I appreciate your time. Are you able to help me understand a bit more what a smart contract call is? Cheers

Comment: Let me rephrase that. I understand a smart contract call is merely a way of interacting with the contract. My confusion is understanding it from the practical POV. Company A interacts with contract X in order to transfer money to Company B. In this case, contract x only interacted with other contracts Y and Z. How is the transfer from Company A and Company B possible if no Ether is actually transferred at all? Hope you can give me a hand here. Cheers

Comment: You can send the ETH to the contract address beforehand, as they did in the given contract (example transaction can be found [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x77f12ef0a98ef04a2ff80ac3f994912e1c7136a1a76a454aced5e5bfbe2e5a9d))

Comment: Nice. Thanks for sharing that txid. Now, going back to the same example. Company A sends eth to contract X beforehand. Meaning that company B can now interact with contract X without requiring Company A to interact directly with Company B? Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes, these companies can communicate through the contract X without communicating directly to each other.